# illegal argument Exception Vertical ScrollBar Policy

Tags: java

[Code+Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNm0T.jpg)
i am Trying to Execute this ScrollPane Basic Code on My Netbeans
but its giving me the Following error
"invalid Vertical ScrollBar Policy"
My Code and the error Screenshot is in the image
please Help

Comment: Post your code and other relevant information in the question.

Comment: You've got the vertical and horizontal scrollbar policies the wrong way round. I found this in about 90 seconds by Googling the exception's error message which took me to the JScrollPane javadoc. And yes, please copy the code snippet and error message into the question itself - far more useful than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The last two arguments to the JScrollPane constructor are in backward order.  You should specify the vertical scrollbar policy, then the horizontal one.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane(java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int)